# Mail service in local GitLab docker container

Tags: docker, email, localhost, gitlab

I've created a local GitLab server for managmenting code versions in my local network (with my team). How can I have a mail notifications about changes in code versions?

This is my container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                                                         NAMES
f3a2c26319dc        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   2 months ago        Up 2 minutes (healthy)   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:22->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7842->7842/tcp, 443/tcp   gitlab
```

My ip is 192.168.0.177, so for accessing to GitLab: 192.168.0.177:7842

Is it possible to send/receive mails in local network?

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Do you have already a mail server in your local network that you want to access from gitlab? Or do you want to run another mail-service container with docker? Or what do you exactly want?

Comment: I'm sorry if I've explained myself wrong @Sebastian. I just want to receive mail notifications of my local projects, that they are in a local GitLab docker container.